# How to send messages to the dead letter queue in Amazon MQ for RabbitMQ using MassTransit?

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, amazon-mq

I need messages that have an error in my saga consumers instead of being sent to the _error queue to be sent to the DLQ, how can I make this configuration?

Is it necessary that the Delayed Message Plugin is activated?

I'm currently trying like this, but after the error the message does not go to any queue and is getting lost.

```
    protected override void ConfigureConsumer(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, IConsumerConfigurator<ContractCreationConsumer> consumerConfigurator)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.ConfigureDeadLetter(x =>
        {
            x.UseFilter(new DeadLetterTransportFilter());
        });

        endpointConfigurator.ConfigureError(x => x.UseFilter(new GenerateFaultFilter()));
    }
```